# Databricks SQL AddColumn While Creating Delta Table

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, dbsql

I am trying to create a delta table with an added column in the DBSQL metastore from a delta bucket. I do not want to pass in the schema as this may change in the bucket over time but I do want to add a column to the metastore only that is a generatedAlways column so it populated with new values as the delta bucket receives new data. This is my code based on Databricks documentation:

```
DeltaTable.createIfNotExists(spark) \
.tableName("golddata.table") \
.addColumn("date", DateType(), generatedAlwaysAs="CAST(concat(year,month,'-01') AS DATE)") \
.location("cloudBucket://golddata/table") \
.execute()
```

This codes gives a schema mismatch error. Is there a way to add a column in Databricks SQL Metastore to the existing schema that is being loaded from my delta bucket? Will using the `generatedAlways` function updated when the data in the bucket is updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add columns to existing Delta Table you have to specify two options:

- `write` or `writeStream` are set with `.option("mergeSchema", "true")`
- `spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled` is set to true

If these two are provided, then Delta should merge in your extra column into existing schema.

Sources:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/update-schema#add-columns-with-automatic-schema-update

Comment: I am using the DeltaTableBuilder to create this table in Databricks SQL  hive from a formatted Delta Table in a storage bucket. This does not have attributes for `write` or `writeStream`.